# Two .htaccess rules not working with each other

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shared/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shared.php [L]
```

But I would also like to remove .php extension with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I have tried a dozen combinations based on answers elsewhere not just on StackOverflow but still cannot get it right, I either render pages not in shared directory unable to open with 500/404 errors or 500 error when I go to /shared.

After further investigation and trial when I add the rules to remove the .php extension it messes up the first rule to route anything under the path of /shared/ to shared.php the path /shared/username are not real locations but the script insures that the correct information is presented. It would be handy to ignore the second rule if the URL has /shared/ in the path? Is that possible? I am not rewriting everything to the /shared/ directory - only when the path reads /shared/username do I want that rule to kick in, everything else should be rewritten to the / base directory.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shared/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shared.php [L]
```

Comment: Have tried that, doing so gives me:

**The requested URL /shared/prefs.php was not found on this server.**

- When I go to `http://myurl/prefs`

When I go to the shared folder: `http://myurl/shared/admin`

I get:

**The requested URL /shared/shared/admin.php was not found on this server.**

Comment: What is correct location of `admin.php` Is it not `shared/admin.php`?

Comment: Also did you place above .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in DOCUMENT_ROOT/shared folder? I need some info about location of your php files, shared.php and .htaccess

Comment: .htaccess is in DOCUMENT_ROOT. Shared folder nor admin.php do not exist. I have users shared documents that I want at a URL of `http://myurl/shared/username` so when I type this in the URL htaccess just serves up shared.php and that script fetches the correct content based on `$user = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`

Comment: I am now getting confused. What do you mean by `Shared folder nor admin.php do not exist.`? I was under impression that you're hiding `.php` extension in first rule.

Comment: Yes for everything else. But id like to have pretty URLs for usernames in a "fake" shared folder. That part of the htaccess works well, its just when I try to remove the .php for static "real" files I get the issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43349/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ian-tearle)

Comment: Ok can you clarify these requirements in your question. For which URLs you want to have pretty feature and how they should be rewritten internally. For examples if URL is `/shared/username` how should that be handled internally. Does `shared.php` exist, if yes then what is its location?